# A word or phrase for someone who is sure of himself

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase for someone who is sure of himself, someone who acts like everything they say is a fact even when it's not.

Comment: "Cock-sure" is a popular idiom.

Comment: What's wrong with 'self-assured'? It's a much less pejorative term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a person who is sure of himself is said to be self-assured or perhaps even self-confident. When you add "who acts like everything they say is fact even when it's not", I have two suggestions you could say that they are:

[**Self-righteous**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/self-righteous): Having or ***characterized by a certainty, especially an unfounded one, that one is totally correct*** or morally superior.

‘self-righteous indignation and complacency’

some synonyms for self-righteous are

> sanctimonious
>
> holier-than-thou
>
> self-satisfied
>
> smug
>
> priggish
>
> complacent
>
> too good to be true
>
> pious
>
> pietistic
>
> moralizing
>
> unctuous
>
> superior
>
> mealy-mouthed
>
> hypocritical

or

[**Pontifical**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pontifical): Characterised by a pompous air of infallibility.

‘such explanations were greeted with pontifical disdain’

Synonyms

> pompous
>
> cocksure
>
> self-important
>
> arrogant
>
> superior

Note that not all of these synonyms will necessarily convey the added meaning of acting self-assured and believing that everything they say is a fact even when it's not.

Comment: Self-righteous means having a sense of moral correctness and/or superiority. It doesn't automatically imply self-confidence.

Answer (score 2):

***Arrogant***, perhaps -

> *["Unpleasantly proud and behaving as if you are more important than, or know more than, other people"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arrogant).*
>
> *["Disposed to give oneself undue importance, aggressively haughty"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/arrogant)*.

Or [***cocky***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cocky).